# Do certificates need to be indented in a YAML file to be read in correctly?

Tags: python, jenkins, yaml, openshift

I currently have a Jenkins pipeline building an application, but I'm running into an issue with injecting a server key (cert) into the YAML file. The server key has been added to the credential manager on Jenkins and I'm pulling it via a variable (withCredentials). Pulling it isn't the issue, simply injecting it so it's readable by the server is.

For reference, the YAML file looks like:

```
edge:
  [...]
  certificates:
    ingress:
      name: certs
      key: |
        ------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        ...
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
      [...]
```

And the cert looks like (yes, there are a lot in one):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

My Python script is

```
import yaml
import os

with open("file.yaml") as f:
  y = yaml.load(f)
  y["edge"]["certificates"]["ingress"]["key"] = os.getenv("KEY_CERT")

with open("file.yaml", "w") as f:
  yaml.dump(y, f)
```

I execute it via shell like:

```
python -c 'exec """\nimport yaml\nimport os\n\nwith open("file.yaml") as f:\n  y = yaml.load(f)\n  y["edge"]["certificates"]["ingress"]["key"] = os.getenv("KEY_CERT")\n\nwith open("file.yaml", "w") as f:\n  yaml.dump(y, f)\n"""'
```

The server logs:
edge:10808: Failed to load trusted CA certificates from /etc/proxy/tls/sidecar/ca.crt

How it looks on the server:

```
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----         TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT         -----END CERTIFICATE-----         -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----         TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT         -----END CERTIFICATE-----         -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----         TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT         -----END CERTIFICATE-----         -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----         TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT         -----END CERTIFICATE-----         -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----         TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT         -----END CERTIFICATE-----         -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----         TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT         -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So does it really matter? And how do I go about fixing it...

(or if there's another way to inject a cert into a YAML file, that'd be great to hear about as well!)

Initially, it was all hard coded, but of course for security concerns, it can't be harded in a production environment.

I've visited a few other StackOverflow responses, but none of them talk about injecting a cert that follows a traditional format as shown in general YAML files.

I expect the server to pick up the cert.

Comment: Additionally, I've tried condensing the certificates into one line, so something like:
```-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT-----END CERTIFICATE-----``` and this also fails

Comment: What exactly does `file.yaml` look like after you run your one-liner? How are you setting the `KEY_CERT` environment variable?

Comment: The file looks like: https://imgur.com/a/GCzEjER (this is with the method of converting the cert into one line of text)

Comment: I think the problem is with how you're setting the `KEY_CERT` environment variable. Please update your question (don't put new information in the comments) to show exactly how you're doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know the solution to this problem. A workaround was simply running a few shell commands to generate the certs and inject them via that method.

Can't really expand on other details as it's specific to the overall project (how it interacts with RH and other components).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

No certificates don't need to be indented. They just need to be loaded from the YAML document in a way that the program doing the loading can work with them. If that has to be in the form of a multiline string you have the option to use a quoted scalar in YAML, which could put everything on one line (with `\n` inserted for newlines. The other option is using a literal scalar (only available in block style), as in your example, and such a scalar needs to be indented.

If you only need one scalar (string) to be a literal style scalar, I recommend you use ruamel.yaml and its `LiteralScalarString` to set the value and then dump.